# How to remove the redundant variable from this 2 line piece of code

Tags: c#

For amusement I'm trying to reduce some code down to as few lines as possible and I've run into a pattern I can't quite figure out how to reduce down to 1 line. As an example I have the following:

```
bool redundant;    
Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList().ForEach(x => redundant = x % 2 == 0 ? ListOfEvens.Add(x): false);
```

Can the above 2 liner of "add the even numbers of 1 through 5" be rewritten with different syntax to be a 1 liner? I think it should be doable because one line is simply declaring an otherwise redundant variable.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not 100% sure what the type of `ListOfEvens` is, but assuming it's `List<int>` you can use `AddRange`:

```
ListOfEvens.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Where(x => x % 2 == 0));
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work, thanks! This was just an example, in my original code the ListOfEvens was a different HashSet<int> but there was no reason I couldn't update it to be a List<int> which let me use AddRange

Answer (score 1):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList().ForEach(x => { if (x % 2 == 0) ListOfEvens.Add(x);});
```